# Cut circle into equal parts in Sketch to implement animation progress bar?

Tags: animation, sketch-app

I have a circle in Sketch 3 that I would like to animate a progress bar in iOS. So I will need to cut the green circle in 30 pieces so I can spin through `circle-01@2x.png` to `circle-30@2x.png` to give the animation effect (`*-01` is 3% of the circle and `*-30` is 99% of the circle).

Is there a way to do this automatically? I couldn't figure it out so I was going to do it manually, but became too difficult and time consuming to measure all the pieces exactly. Is there a technique to accomplish this?

Below is a screenshot of my Sketch file (green circle), and a screenshot of an example of how I would like to cut it up (blue circle from another sample project but don't know how they did that).

[image: screenshot of my Sketch file (green circle)]

To something like this:
[image: screenshot of an example]

Comment: I don't know anything about iOS (yet) but going through an image for each frame of the animation (like a GIF) seems crazy inefficient. There's gotta be a better way.  Take a look at these two libraries: https://github.com/CardinalNow/iOS-CircleProgressView and https://github.com/kentya6/KYCircularProgress

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use [GB-Sketch-Segmentcircle](https://github.com/design4use/gb-sketch-segmentcircle) plugin to achieve this.

- Download and install the plugin (see link above) ;
- In the plugin menu : Segmented circles > Create segmented circle

[image]

- Choose options :

[image]

- Circle is segmented so you just have to copy / modify the circle segments to match the desired result.

[image]

Hope it helps !